# A script to run emacs in cmd

Tags: prompt, script

Good day,
I created the following script in order to run emacs 27.1 in cmd without gui:

```
$ cd \Users\xxxxxx\emacs-27.1-x86_64\bin
$ emacs-27.1.exe -nw %1
```

An elementary script which I named `demacs`. Emacs runs in `cmd` and divides the buffer in two sides. In the left sides there is the source file, in the right side the preview.

I have installed `latex-preview-pane` and it works correctly, but using this script no. The right side is not able to read the pdf and shows only strange characters.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Try evaluating `(image-type-available-p 'png)` with `M-:` and see if the answer is `t`.  Perhaps the terminal is not capable of showing PDF files by way of GhostScript making PNG files that get displayed in the buffer; or, perhaps you don't have GhostScript separately installed with a PATH that Emacs scans; or, perhaps you are missing the `dll` files in the `bin` directory of Emacs which it needs to display PNG images as well as other image types.  I would first get things working with the GUI version and then switch to the terminal once things are good to go ...

Comment: I use ghostscript with emacs with gui.